# PostgreSQL Upsert with Medoo

Tags: php, postgresql, medoo

I am using PostgreSQL with PHP, and i want to use Upsert with Medoo,

Right now i am using query() function like this:

`$data = $database->query("MY UPSERT QUERY")->fetchAll();`

I want to create a function in Medoo for Upsert, Any idea for it?

Comment: What are you fetching from `UPSERT` query? I mean you can if you use `RETURNING`, but generally those don't return anything.
`query()` in this framework accepts `RAW SQL`, what did you try and didn't work?

Comment: I want that if a record was inserted/updated in database then its id/primary key will be return. In case of insert it is newly inserted id. And in update case it is existing id.

Comment: You don't know how upserts work in PostgreSQL or you are asking for something else? Upserts are done by `INSERT [..] ON CONFLICT [..]` Clause.